# How can missing values in the target variable be substituted using Python?

Tags: clustering, dataset, data-imputation, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset with some missing values in the target variable (label). Can I use clustering to find those missing label values? What other methods can be applied to resolve such an issue in Python?

Here is a sample of the dataset:

> [image: Example of issue]

Answer (score 1):

Why **NOT** clustering?

You dont want classification, because classification requires `labels`. Since you've already mentioned, there are missing labels. Try the following approach;

- split the data into two halves;
- one half with labelled data and other half with unlabelled data.

  - Split the labelled data again into 3 parts; one for training, second half for testing and third half for validation. Create a model using any appropriate method for the training data. Then test this model on the test and validation data. Examine the validation results to determine the type of labels. Then assign these labels to the missing data set.

Answer (score 0):

Why clustering?

What you want to do is **classification, not clustering**.

The objects where you have labels serve as your training data.

Whenever you have training labels, you want to use them and not discard them.

Answer (score 0):

**Classification approach:**
If the dataset has a fair volume of data of non-missing, a classifier can be built, then, the developed classifier can be used for the observation whose missing label.

**Clustering approach:**
Clustering could also be a solution by which it groups similar data points together, and, then, the similar data points could give the value of the missing from the known label of the same group, however, same group of data point could give more than one label.

**Manual approach:**
If number of observations with missing label is not that big, manually manipulation is one of the reliable approaches to fill the NULL values of labels. Manual validation for the above approaches is also important to checking the validity of the updated labels using either classification/clustering. This is because *the most reliable the label is the best fitting-performance the model could be*.

Recently, I have heard about ***KNN-Imputation***, but, honestly, I have not given it a try. It could be an easy and efficient solution.